# Does `EstimateGas` work for cross-contract call?

Tags: solidity, gas

I found that the result of `estimate gas` is not accurate when I make cross-contract call in my contract. As a result, transactions alwalys fail due to `out of gas`.

This is my code to estimate gas:

```
 const gas = await targetContract.methods[methodName].apply(null, arguments).estimateGas({from: account});
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

https://blog.emn178.cc/en/post/using-web3-js-to-parse-custom-error/

```
import { decodeContractErrorData } from 'web3-eth-abi';
...
decodeContractErrorData(myContract._errorsInterface, e.innerError);
```